# Planner/Task endpoint not certain when PATCH data gets updated

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was trying to use the planner endpoint on version 1 of the graph. The main goal for me is to update the status of a task and decide whether it is ‘completed’ or ‘to do’. The first thing I do is to get all tasks from myself. See the endpoint below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/planner/tasks






 function plannerCompleteTask(id, etag) {
                var specialEtag = etag.replace(/\\/g, "");
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var endpoint = config.baseGraphApiUrl + 'planner/tasks/' + id;


            var data = {
                "percentComplete": "100"
            };

            var configRest = {
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                    "If-Match": specialEtag
                }
            }


            //"completedDateTime": "2018-02-15T07:56:25.7951905Z",

            $http.patch(endpoint, data, configRest).then(function (result) {
                console.log('log code', result);
                deferred.resolve(result.status);

            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

I will create the following request

[image]

This will return a status: 204 with no content.

If I rerun the query with a "percentageCompleted: 0" in the body I get the following error.

[image]

Also If I try to log the request I get back from the AJAX call it doesn't give me back anything. As if there is no error handling being send back. I would need this because I have to reload the data in my application; but right now my code runs before the changes on the graph get completed, yet it returns a 204 status.

So I am clueless to find out when the call doesn't work or to find out when it is finished. Did anyone faced this issue before?

Thanks for reading and any help would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the "prefer" header. If in your patch request you provide the "prefer" header with value "return=representation", the result of the patch will be final task data, including the new etag, with 200 status code, instead of default behavior of returning 204 "no content" status code.

Write operations in Planer are asynchronous. So, when possible, you should always update your local data based on the results of write operations with the prefer header, instead of reading them again.

In your requests, since you are reading the data before the task update is complete, essentially you are updating the same state of the task to be completed and not completed at the same time, which is the reason for the conflict.